# C# execute stored procedure with context.Connection

Tags: c#

I prepare a SQL call with :

```
var cmd_count = context.Connection.CreateCommand(sql_count);
```

and parse over the results with :

```
using (var reader = cmd_count.ExecuteReader())
```

This doesn't seem to work with stored procedures. There is an option

```
context.Connection.ExecuteStoredProcedure(DataSet setname, string procedure)
```

but it looks like the procedure gets executed right in this command. Is there  way to run my procedure and parse the result in the same way as for a regular SQL string? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310070/how-to-call-a-parameterized-stored-procedure-by-using-ado-net-and-visu), you have to set the option for running stored procedures in ADO.NET:

```
cmd_count.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```